# PHP - Call the same method for a collection of objects

Tags: php, database, design-patterns, iteration

I have to call the same method for each object of an objects array, iteratively. This method contains a database query.

Is there a **pattern** that I can follow to achieve this, avoiding to perform the same query N times (with related cons)?

I'm thinking about *prepared statements* but I don't want ending to write another piece of code that only does this.

Comment: Prepared statements are intended to be used with iteration - that's where you will see the biggest gain from using them. If you aren't using them, then you should definitely start.

Depending on the query, it might be possible to concatenate all of the array objects into a single query. It also depends on what you want to do after the query is processed. We need more information.

Comment: The first example that comes to mind might be: I have to change the user group from A to B for a set of users. Is there a way to organize the User class method, say "updateUserGroup", so that if called within an iteration, the query is prepared only one time?

Comment: You could set a Boolean member on the class to indicate this.

Comment: Could you please bring me an example to use as starting point? How can I preserve the prepared statement through the method calls?

Comment: Add it as a member of your class. Something like `class MyClass { protected $lastPreparedStatement; public function updateUserGroup() { $this->lastPreparedStatement = ...; //Set the last prepared statement } };` There are all kinds of ways you could accomplish this. Your question is so broad, it's impossible for me to give you an example. Try doing it yourself using class, and then if you have specific questions, open a new SO question.